# Does FQL have a "NOT NULL" type operator?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm messing around with FQL, and I have this query:

```
SELECT created_time, attachment, message FROM stream  WHERE source_id = me() LIMIT 1000
```

which returns 1000 results, most not relevant to me. I'd like to filter, for example, on MESSAGE IS NOT NULL. Is that (or something equivalent) possible with FQL?

Answer (score 12):

Just adding `AND message` to the WHERE clause works as well – an empty value is considered “false” by FQL.

Answer (score 3):

Add `type` to the `SELECT` clause and in the `WHERE` clause add `AND type > 0`.